# Plotting a Hill function

Tags: plotting

I've Just recently gotten this program and cant plot this function,
F(X)=1/(1+(X/K)^n) for X=0 to 4 nmol/m^3, K=1 nmol/m^3, F(X)= 0 to 1, and n=1,2,4,8,16

Now I know how to specify the limits and what not but im not sure how to enter in the different values for n, any idea of the code? Plus every time I try, mathematica just keeps simplifying to x^2. Im also a bit knowledgeless on legends and axis labels etc.

edit: Where it came from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_%28biochemistry%29

Thankyou!

Comment: It is best to (additionally) include *Mathematica* code in this kind of question; it helps people to see what you are trying and where it might be going wrong.  Oh, and welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: Plus, `K` is a built-in symbol and the documentation centre is pretty extensive, so you might wanna go there first.

Comment: @Sektor `K` does not represent anything "built-in", there's no problem with using it.

Comment: @Pickett `K[1]` etc are used internally relatively rarely, so I would say `K = 1` is a relatively safe thing to do.  I would avoid it,though.  -- Steve, perhaps `Table` or `SetDelayed`: `F[x_, n_] := 1/(1+(x/k)^n)`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point, forgot about that.

Comment: Let me just leave this reference: [Hill equation (biochemistry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)). The question confused me at first because I had assumed it was related to the Hill differential equation (a generalization of the Mathieu equation).

Comment: Sorry about that, I will make sure to include code and be more specific next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To deal with the other aspects: legends, labels. I suggest looking through documentation and trying/playing as colours, and other style elements are highly customizable.

```
f[k_, n_, x_] := 1/(1 + (x/k)^n)
r = PowerRange[1, 16, 2];
ex = f[1, #, x] & /@ r;
Plot[ex, {x, 0, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, r, LegendLabel -> "n"], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Concentration (nmol\[CenterDot]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\
\(m\), \(-3\)]\))", "Saturation"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you much appreaciated! I have learned a great deal just by reading through your code and googling

Answer (score 3):

I did not try terribly hard to follow your description but hopefully this at least gives you a start:

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + (x/k)^n)

expr = Table[f[x], {n, {1, 2, 4, 8, 16}}, {k, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{1/(1 + x)}, {1/(1 + x^2)}, {1/(1 + x^4)}, {1/(1 + x^8)}, {1/(1 + x^16)}}
> ```

```
Plot[expr, {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Notice that I use lower case letters to start all Symbol names; capital letters can conflict with built-ins.

Comment: Thank you aswell! if only I could accept 2 answers!